# android.media.MediaExtractorを使用してicy-metaを取得したい

Tags: android

[android.media.MediaExtractor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html)を使用してShoutcast Serverからストリーミング中の音楽の
メタデータ(icy-meta)を取得する事は可能でしょうか？

icy-meta から 楽曲のタイトル、アーティスト名を取得したいと考えています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediaExtractor`を使用して、という前提ですと不可能という答えになります。

加えて言えば、ストリーミング中の楽曲のメタデータを取得することはできません。[SHOUTcastのプロトコル](https://forums.radiotoolbox.com/viewtopic.php?t=74)はメタデータの後にバイナリストリームが送られてくる構造のためです。

また、実際にメタデータとしてアーティスト名が付与されるかどうかは、配信局に依存します（インターネットラジオ局の名前しか取得できない場合もあります）。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
やはりそうですか。 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996697/get-the-icy-meta-using-the-android-media-extractor/28004730?iemail=1&noredirect=1#28004730
 のような形で自前でバイナリを操作するしかなさそうですね。

Comment: [Get Stream Metadata with Plain Java for Your Android App](http://uniqueculture.net/2010/11/stream-metadata-plain-java/)の実装を使われている人が多い印象です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり InputStream からバイナリを解析してメタを取得するしかなさそうですね。
そこでMediaExtractorを使用しせずバイナリのデコードでつまづいてしまいました。　新たに **[投稿](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/4861/android-mediaextractor-%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-mediacodec-%E3%83%87%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)** させて頂きましたので、見て頂ければと思います。